# JUNRAR : Application freezes until extraction is not completed

Tags: java, android

i have some kind of problem with junrar , i am able to extract rar files using junrar but it is slow and my application stops to respond until extraction is not completed if any one having solution or alternate of junrar please help me. i have also used junrar in service but same result please help...
here is my code to extract

```
private static File createFile(FileHeader fh, File destination) {
    File f = null;
    String name = null;
    if (fh.isFileHeader() && fh.isUnicode()) {
     name = fh.getFileNameW();
    } else {
     name = fh.getFileNameString();
    }
    f = new File(destination, name);
    if (!f.exists()) {
     try {
            f = makeFile(destination, name);
     } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error creating the new file: " ,f.getName(), e);
     }
    }
    return f;
}
private static File makeFile(File destination, String name)
        throws IOException {

       String[] dirs = name.split("\\\\");
       if (dirs == null) {
        return null;
       }
       String path = "";
       int size = dirs.length;
       if (size == 1) {
        return new File(destination, name);
       } else if (size > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.length - 1; i++) {
               path = path + File.separator + dirs[i];
               new File(destination, path).mkdir();
        }
        path = path + File.separator + dirs[dirs.length - 1];
        File f = new File(destination, path);
        f.createNewFile();
        return f;
       } else {
        return null;
       }
   }
public void extractRar(File filerar,final String location)
{
    Archive a = null;
    try {
        a = new Archive(new FileVolumeManager(filerar));
} catch (RarException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
    if (a != null) {
        a.getMainHeader().print();
        FileHeader fh = a.nextFileHeader();
        while (fh != null) {

                try {
                    if(fh.isDirectory())
                    {

                            Log.e("directory", fh.getFileNameString());
                            if(fh.getFileNameString().contains("."))
                            {
                                directory=fh.getFileNameString();
                                Log.e("Directory name",directory);
                            }

                    }else{
                        file=fh.getFileNameString();
                        Log.e("File name",file);

                        File out = createFile(fh, new File(location));
                        Log.e("observe file",location+file.substring(0, file.indexOf("\\main")).replace("\\", "/"));
                        final Timer mytimer=new Timer();
                        mytimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if(new File(location+file.replace("\\", "/")).exists())
                                Log.e("size", size(new File(location+file.replace("\\", "/")).length()));
                                intent.putExtra("file_length", new File(location+file.replace("\\", "/")).length());
                                intent.putExtra("status", "extracting");
                                getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

                            }
                        }, 0, 50);

                        System.out.println(out.getAbsolutePath());
                        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
                        a.extractFile(fh, os);
                        mytimer.cancel();
                        os.close();}
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RarException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fh = a.nextFileHeader(); 

        }

        intent.putExtra("status", "completed");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Extracted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the extract or other functions inside a thread like below:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {         

            //Call function here
            }
      };
Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
mythread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just create a Thread and add your extract login into run() method:

```
// Download Contents
   Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
                //Add extract logic here
                }
    };
    t.start();
```